# Postgres: Get nextval in sequence without actually incrementing sequence?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

It looks like `select nextval('table_name')` actually does the value increment.

My goal is to "predict" the `nextval` value on all tables in the database without actually making any incrementation. This should be a read-only operation.

I cannot run the `select nextval` on a read-only connection since it's actually trying to make a transaction. I would like to be able to query this and monitor the sequences on a read-only replica database.

How would you tackle this and meet the goal?

Comment: An int id column overflowed due to a bug in the custom stored proc that rebuilds our sequences... Until the root cause can be identified and fixed, I want to have insight to any tables that might overflow their data types by a high sequence number as at least a preventative measure.

Comment: That would be great to redesign.  However it's a 10 year old legacy software design stack and I'm just trying to earn my paycheck not here to redesign everything. I'm a sysadmin just trying to resolve a problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would assume that `SELECT currval('seq_name') + 1` or `SELECT last_value + 1 FROM seq_name` would be the answer, but that's only if you're incrementing by `1`, or you know the increment off-hand.

If you're not incrementing by `1` and you don't know the increment, then try this:

```
SELECT currval('seq_name') + i.inc
  FROM (SELECT seqincrement AS inc
          FROM pg_sequence
         WHERE seqrelid = 'seq_name'::regclass::oid) AS i;
```

or

```
SELECT last_value + i.inc
  FROM seq_name,
      (SELECT seqincrement AS inc
         FROM pg_sequence
        WHERE seqrelid = 'seq_name'::regclass::oid) AS i;
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on previous answers I realised that it fails for the first value added: The query returns 2 instead on 1 when there are no values added.
Here is my solution:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN is_called THEN last_value + i.inc 
        ELSE last_value END ) AS nextvalue
  FROM myserial,
      (SELECT seqincrement AS inc 
       FROM pg_sequence 
       WHERE seqrelid = 'myserial'::regclass::oid) AS i;
```